# Toggle classes for children of currently active parent element

Tags: jquery, css

Right now I have three sections of checkboxes--this is an example of how a section is setup:

```
<div class="color-swatches">
      <div class="swatch">
        <img src="/img/Apothecary_Swatch.jpg" class="swatch-icon image">
        <p class="color-name">Apothecary</p>
        <div class="check off"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="swatch">
        <img src="/img/Arbor_Swatch.jpg" class="swatch-icon image">
        <p class="color-name">Arbor</p>
        <div class="check off"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="swatch">
        <img src="/img/Bubble_Swatch.jpg" class="swatch-icon image">
        <p class="color-name">Bubbles</p>
        <div class="check off"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="swatch">
        <img src="/img/TransparentSpacer.gif" class="swatch-icon image">
        <p class="color-name">Classic</p>
        <div class="check off"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="swatch">
        <img src="/img/LadyBug_Swatch.jpg" class="swatch-icon image">
        <p class="color-name">Lady Bug</p>
        <div class="check off"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="swatch">
        <img src="/img/Burst_Swatch.jpg" class="swatch-icon image">
        <p class="color-name">Starburst</p>
        <div class="check off"></div>
      </div>
```

`.color-swatches` contains the entire selection of checkboxes for a section. Right now, I have things set up so that you can click on an image (which has the class `.swatch-icon`) and the div with the class `.check` will replace the `.off` class with the .on one (.off has an image of an inactive checkbox and `.on` has an image of an active one).

What I need to do is make sure that, for each `.color-swatches` div, only ONE swatch-icon is "selected" (in other words, for on one `.check` div can have the `.on` class at a time). Right now, I can select any or all swatches inside a `.color-swatches` div, which is not what I want. What can I do to alter my jQuery to make this functionality happen?

Here is the jQuery I have at the moment:

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.color-swatches').each(function() {

         $('.swatch').each(function(i, n) {

            $(n).find('.swatch-icon').bind('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var currentCheck = $(this).find('.check');

                if(currentCheck.hasClass('off')){
                  currentCheck.removeClass('off');
                  currentCheck.addClass('on');
                }

            }.bind($(this)));

         });

    });

  });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can massively simplify your code by adding the class to the element that was clicked and removing it from all other `.check` elements. Try this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.swatch-icon').click(function() {
            var $container = $(this).closest('.color-swatches');
            $container.find('.check').removeClass('on');
            $(this).siblings('.check').addClass('on');
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uz0gn4qm/)

Comment: I was about to post this as well. It shows that the default state (`off`) is redundant.

Comment: This is good, but without the off class, then the swatches don't have that inactive checkbox image attached. They need to, by default have that inactive image until they are clicked, then they have the active image which is contained in the on class.

Comment: Then you can add that image to the standard `.check` class in CSS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated my jQuery with what you have now setup, and that seems to be working exactly how I need it. Thanks!

Comment: Why you just ignore `off`` css class?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I didn't ignore it. Having an extra class simply for the default state is redundant, hence I suggested the OP set the default styling on the `.check` clause, and have the active state set in the `.on`. That way you only need to add/remove a single class to set the state.

Comment: Understood, just saw your comments in relation to that above. Thanks